# How to Django queryset orderd_by in minimum time likes average max?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**Info:** I want to get queryset with `order_by` max like at minimum average time.

In other words, In minimum time likes average max. Which have more average `likes` in less average time.

```py
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Model.objects.values(
    'published_at',
    'likes',
).aggregate(
    viewers=Avg(F('current_time') - Avg(F('published_at')) / F('likes'))
).order_by('-viewers')
```

Comment: If I understood this correctly,  logically this makes no sense. Wouldn't the old posts will get heavily punished here because relative to the current time they were published way back? Unless you are tracking when every like was made to a post, there's no way to tell which post got the highest number of likes within the least amount of time.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into `annotate()`, as you want the Model instances ordered by this logic eventually. `aggregate()` returns an aggregated result, not individual instances and you cannot add more calls after it.